# Color adjusting LED ceiling light intermittent issues

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, dimmer-switch, recessed-lighting

I recently installed CE color changing (5 temperature settings) LED all-in-one fixtures in my bedrooms and have been having an odd issue. I wired four fixtures with 12/2 Romex in parallel out of a Lutron Caseta wireless dimmer, compatible with LEDs. The fixtures have a physical temperature control 5 position selector switch and we use the 3500K setting. The second light in the circuit will power on very dimly, and show a noticeable flicker. I am talking like you can barely see any light coming from it. After 30 seconds or so, it will  begin to operate normally. I have changed 3 fixtures, ensured all wiring is tight, and even replaced the switch. It still persists every few cycles.

Finally, the other issue is occasionally, the second light on another will get stuck at either its lowest or highest color temperature setting, regardless of color selector position on the light upon power on. cycling power doesn't clear it but it will go back to the desired setting eventually. No clear pattern i have noticed.

The only other information I can think may be relevant is that they are fed through an AFCI outlet, and that is fed by a 20A tandem breaker. Additionally, I am getting 120.2- 120.6 VAC at the breaker and switch.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain those LED fixtures are dimmable? Do you have a model number you could share?

Comment: There also seems to be some confusion in the terminology you're using. "3500K" is not a brightness setting, it's a color temperature.

Comment: I will add the model number tomorrow, and yes, the light has a temperature control switch, and regardless of that position, one light on the circuit will get stuck at the lowest or highest temperature. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: The Caseta controls the brightness. What (switch? app?)) controls the color?

Comment: The color is controlled via the selector on the fixtures themselves, 2700k ,3000k, 3500k, 4000k, 5000k,

Comment: it sounds to me like those bulbs don't like that dimmer. do the bulbs work fine in other lamps?

Comment: Have you tried each of the fixtures on a circuit that has only one fixture such a bedroom with a switch that controls only one light ?

Answer (score 1):

### You appear to have some defective fixtures.

Return those ones and get hopefully non-defective replacements. Quality control is not what it used to be, so shipping defective products to stores is all too common these days, and you become the "quality control" by returning the defective ones under warranty. Or profits go up if you got past the warranty time before finding the defect.

Welcome to the 21st century.

Comment: three fixtures in a row with the same issue? Is the quality really that bad?

Comment: Well, let's see. We have on the one hand the rather simple, straightforward delivery of power to the fixtures by your electrical system, and on the other hand you have a bunch of complex electronics mass produced as cheaply as possible. Feel free to demount the fixtures and move them around your house, as I originally suggested when I thought they were bulbs, but one bad run of parts or process error on a production line can produce thousands of defective units which will end up in the same box, on the same pallet and ultimately on the same shelf at the store, so "3 in a row" isn't shocking.

Comment: If you do move fixtures and the problem actually stays at that location, rather than following the fixture, then something peculiar is going on and connections need to be checked carefully. And moving a "works good" fixture there, while moving the problem fixture elsewhere is a solid check on where the problem lies.

Comment: problem moved with the light. so yes, 3 defective lights in a row. Now all is working as it should be.